# In SSL/TLS communication with IIS, Certificate Request does not contain my client cert

Tags: authentication, ssl, iis, certificate

One of my clients java/Cold Fusion application is trying to access my WCF web service endpoint using client certificate mutual authentication.
We moved our wcf service to windows 2008 R2/IIS 7 machine and generated new certificate using 3rd party CA. After the change, client is getting 403.13 error.
On investigation, I found that the Certificate Request does not include the new certificate in the distinguished names list. 
How can I configure IIS to include the client certificate in the trusted certificate list?
[image]

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/varunm/2013/06/10/how-to-create-custom-certificate-trust-list-in-windows-server-2k8-r2/ CTL configuration is a little complex but it should resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can't add trusted certificates, it's done on machine level. If you open MMC and add the certificate plugin you should be able to add it to the Trusted Root Certification Authorities on the server.